# Does the std library contain equivalent to boost small_vector and static_vector?

Tags: c++, c++23

Those 2 containers are useful. Allocated on the stack up to some size, then on the heap.
And the other, max compile time capacity with a runtime number of elements.

Is there a equivalent in the std library?
Are there proposals for future versions of the std library?

Comment: Look into PMR containers. Like `std::pmr::vector`

Comment: Waiting behind `constexpr` ambitions: https://youtu.be/I8QJLGI0GOE?feature=shared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a equivalent in the std library?

Not as of this writing.

> Are there proposals for future versions of the std library?

For `static_vector`: [P0843](https://wg21.link/p0843).

For `small_vector`: [P0274](https://wg21.link/p0274).